# Is 12 amu for Carbon-12 exact or rounded?

Tags: mass, definition, physical-chemistry, metrology

I'm having a difficult time understanding how Carbon-12 has an atomic mass of 12. Each proton and neutron has an atomic mass that is just slightly above 1 amu, so wouldn't Carbon-12 also be above 12?
Neutron = 1.0034 amu
Proton = 1.0073 amu
Carbon-12 = 6 protons and 6 neutrons.
AMU of 6 protons (6.0438amu) and 6 neutrons (6.0204amu) = 12.0642amu
I understand atomic weight, being the average of mass of isotopes on earth. But I do not understand how Carbon-12 = 12 amu, unless is is just rounded down to a whole number for simplicity purposes. If someone could please shed some light upon this I'd be most grateful!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332972/2451

Answer (score 6):

Carbon12 is 12 *unified* amu by definition (see David's comment below).

The masses you quote for free protons and neutrons are not the same as their mass when bound in a nucleus. The binding energy of C12 is around 92MeV which accounts for the missing 0.064amu in your example.

Comment: Re "Carbon12 is 12 amu by definition": That should be "The mass of one $^{12}C$ atom in its rest state is exactly 12 unified atomic mass units, by definition (currently)." Being a bit pedantic, amu refers to the old $^{16}O$ standard. It's better to be precise and use either unified atomic mass units or Daltons, or their abbreviations u or Da. Regarding "currently": This may change with the proposed redefinition of the SI.

Comment: Martin Becket, thank you for your response. So what you're saying is that when protons and neutrons become binded together they lose 0.064amu? If I interpret your response correctly, where then does this mass go?

Comment: David Hammen, reading your response about Daltons helps me understand, I think. Daltons are essentially equivalent the the number of protons and/or neutrons? Each particle equating to 1 dalton. Whereas the amu in other situations (the amu of a single proton being  1.0073amu) its somewhat of a different unit, pertaining more to mass rather than of a quantity? I hope I don't come off supremely ignorant, I'm new to the studies of Chemistry and am self educating prior to the beginning of the semester. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @Dive the extra mass goes to energy (e=mc^2). Dalton and amu are (essentially) the average mass of a proton+neutron. A Dalton or unified amu is 1/12 the mass of a C12 nucleus.  In chemistry you would give the mass of a molecule in Daltons, in physics it gets a bit complicated because the mass of a particle depends on its state - you wouldn't normally state the mass of a proton or neutron in Daltons

Comment: I see. So my question was reaching out into physics which deviates from the chemistry definition of amu, correct?
To assure my understanding, an example; O18 would have an amu of 18, correct? And I127 has an amu of 127. Yes?

Comment: @dive - almost (good enough for Chemistry). O18 has 18 nucleons but won't be exactly 18amu because the binding energy will be different, it is only exactly 12.0 for C12

Comment: @Dive, for chemistry purposes, only the ratios of masses matter when doing a chemical reaction.  Because of this, chemists (?) some time ago decided that since organic life is based on carbon, they would arbitrarily let carbon have an atomic mass of 12.0 amu.  All other elements in the periodic table are "ratioed" relative to this.  This means that when I weigh out exactly 12 g of carbon, and 31.9988 g of oxygen, and heat them to a high temperature, I get a complete reaction to CO2 with no carbon or oxygen left over.  The ratio of 31.9988/12 is important to get the amount of oxygen correct.

Comment: @DavidWhite - IIRC Carbon was chosen because it is easier to separate the isotopes to get pure C12 rather than the O16/17/18 mix in the previous standard. And by moving away from Oxygen there was no ambiguity about which standard you were on. I don't know if having a solid at room temperature also helped - was the mass done by stochiometry or mass-spec in the 60s?

Answer (score 3):

Reading your comments to the other answer, I feel like something should be clarified here.

In an atomic nucleus, a number of protons and neutrons are in a bound state -- just like an electron and a proton in a Hydrogen atom.
Such a bound state of particles has a *binding energy*.
Imagine you begin with all the parts of the nucleus (the partons) infinitely far apart, at this point their potential energy is zero.
If you move them together, once they are close enough to feel the strong nuclear force, they will attract each other / "fall in a potential well".
The potential energy they are losing during this process is the binding energy $E_b$.

Now, the total energy of the system is
$$ E = \sum_{\text{parton } k} m_k\, c^2 - E_b . $$
This is the energy of the bound state, the nucleus, *at rest* and therefore corresponds to its rest mass:
$$ M = E/c^2 = \sum_k m_k - \frac{E_b}{c^2} . $$
You can see there is a *mass deficit*: The mass of the nucleus is smaller than the sum of the masses of its components.

It is very hard to calculate the mass deficit of a nucleus; in fact, this is a many-body problem which can not be analytically solved. You might be interested in the [semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) of Bethe and Weizsäcker or in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Atomic_mass&oldid=786890013#Mass_defects_in_atomic_masses) of binding energy per nucleus for various isotopes.

Finally, C12 has 6 pairs of protons and neutrons, O16 has 8 pairs, but the mass of O16 is not exactly 8/6 times the mass of C12 but again slightly less. One u is now simply defined to be 1/12 the mass of a C12 atom, hence all smaller nuclei tend to have slightly "too high" masses and all larger nuclei tend to have "too small" masses.

Comment: Wow, fascinating! You've got me so very excited to progress through my chemistry studies and really be able to connect all of this information. I see I have much to learn and I'm delighted by this. Thank you so much for this clarification! There are many variables in consideration pertaining to my question that are beyond my current capacity of understanding... for now. Thanks again, really appreciate this!